Subversion wildcard access not allowing users to delete files
I am using Subversion 1.10 which claims to work with wildcards in path authorization.
I have a large group of project folders (2000+) containing restricted and unrestricted sub-folders in each Trunk and Tag. My current devs have access to both, but a new group can only access the unrestricted.
Folder structure looks like this in a big folder called Projects
Project_Folder
- Client1
- - Tags
- - - Release1
- - - - 1_Unrestricted
- - - - 2_Restricted
- - - - 3_Restricted
- - - - 4_Unrestricted
- - + Release2
- - + Release3
- - Trunk
- - - 1_Unrestricted
- - - 2_Restricted
- - - 3_Restricted
- - - 4_Unrestricted
+ Client2

I use this in my authz file:
[repo:/Projects]
@group1=rw
@group2=rw

[:glob:repo:/Projects/**/2_Restricted]
@group2=
[:glob:repo:/Projects/**/3_Restricted]
@group2=

Group 2 has full read and write access to the unrestricted folder, and can do all activities that group 1 can, except for delete files. When attempting to delete files, group 2 gets an access denied error. Is this a known issue or something that I set up incorrectly?

"and can do all activities that group 1 can, except for delete files" -- the authz configuration you show in your question grands identical permissions to group1 and group2 in the "unrestricted" directories.

It seems to work as documented. I'm working with Subversion 1.14.3.
I started by creating a repository under /repos and starting up svnserve:
mkdir -p /repos
svnadmin create /repos/example
svnserve -d -r /repos --log-file /tmp/svnserve.log

Next, I set up svnserve.conf, passwd, and authz:
cat > /repos/example/conf/svnserver.conf <<EOF
[general]
anon-access = read
auth-access = write
password-db = passwd
authz-db = authz
EOF

cat > /repos/example/conf/passwd <<EOF
[users]
alice = secret
bob  = secret
carol = secret
david = secret
EOF

cat > /repos/example/conf/authz <<EOF
[groups]
group1=alice,bob
group2=carol,david

[example:/projects]
@group1=rw
@group2=rw

[:glob:example:/projects/**/2_restricted]
@group2=
[:glob:example:/projects/**/3_restricted]
@group2=
EOF

Then I checked out the empty repository and set up a directory structure that roughly mirrors your example:
svn checkout --username alice svn://localhost:3690/example
cd example/
svn mkdir --parents projects/client1/{tags,trunk}
svn mkdir --parents projects/client1/tags/release1/{1_unrestricted,2_restricted,3_restricted,4_unrestricted}
svn mkdir --parents projects/client1/trunk/{1_unrestricted,2_restricted,3_restricted,4_unrestricted}
find . -name '[0-9]_*' -exec bash -c 'touch {}/file{1,2}; svn add {}/file{1,2}' \;

This gets me the following structure (and in each leaf directory there are two files, file1 and file2):
.
└── projects
    └── client1
        ├── tags
        │   └── release1
        │       ├── 1_unrestricted
        │       ├── 2_restricted
        │       ├── 3_restricted
        │       └── 4_unrestricted
        └── trunk
            ├── 1_unrestricted
            ├── 2_restricted
            ├── 3_restricted
            └── 4_unrestricted

Finally, I checked everything into the repository:
svn commit --username alice -m 'Initial structure'


With the above configuration, we can see that members of group1 are able to see the entire directory structure:
$ svn ls -R --username alice svn://localhost:3690/example/projects
client1/
client1/tags/
client1/tags/release1/
client1/tags/release1/1_unrestricted/
client1/tags/release1/1_unrestricted/file1
client1/tags/release1/1_unrestricted/file2
client1/tags/release1/2_restricted/
client1/tags/release1/2_restricted/file1
client1/tags/release1/2_restricted/file2
client1/tags/release1/3_restricted/
client1/tags/release1/3_restricted/file1
client1/tags/release1/3_restricted/file2
client1/tags/release1/4_unrestricted/
client1/tags/release1/4_unrestricted/file1
client1/tags/release1/4_unrestricted/file2
client1/trunk/
client1/trunk/1_unrestricted/
client1/trunk/1_unrestricted/file1
client1/trunk/1_unrestricted/file2
client1/trunk/2_restricted/
client1/trunk/2_restricted/file1
client1/trunk/2_restricted/file2
client1/trunk/3_restricted/
client1/trunk/3_restricted/file1
client1/trunk/3_restricted/file2
client1/trunk/4_unrestricted/
client1/trunk/4_unrestricted/file1
client1/trunk/4_unrestricted/file2

But a member of group2 can only see the unrestricted directories:
$ svn ls -R --username david svn://localhost:3690/example/projects
client1/
client1/tags/
client1/tags/release1/
client1/tags/release1/1_unrestricted/
client1/tags/release1/1_unrestricted/file1
client1/tags/release1/1_unrestricted/file2
client1/tags/release1/4_unrestricted/
client1/tags/release1/4_unrestricted/file1
client1/tags/release1/4_unrestricted/file2
client1/trunk/
client1/trunk/1_unrestricted/
client1/trunk/1_unrestricted/file1
client1/trunk/1_unrestricted/file2
client1/trunk/4_unrestricted/
client1/trunk/4_unrestricted/file1
client1/trunk/4_unrestricted/file2

If I attempt to commit a change that deletes a file in a restricted directory as a member of group2, it will fail as expected:
$ svn rm projects/client1/tags/release1/1_unrestricted/file1
D         projects/client1/tags/release1/1_unrestricted/file1
$ svn rm projects/client1/tags/release1/2_restricted/file1
D         projects/client1/tags/release1/2_restricted/file1
$ svn commit --username david -m "Remove files"
Deleting       projects/client1/tags/release1/1_unrestricted/file1
Deleting       projects/client1/tags/release1/2_restricted/file1
Committing transaction...
svn: E220004: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E220004: Access denied

If I only make changes in the unrestricted directories, I am able to commit the change:
$ svn rm projects/client1/tags/release1/1_unrestricted/file1
D         projects/client1/tags/release1/1_unrestricted/file1
$ svn commit --username david -m "Remove files"
Deleting       projects/client1/tags/release1/1_unrestricted/file1
Committing transaction...
Committed revision 3.


This might be an issue with 1.10. I'll try to upgrade and see if that fixes it.
